# Returning from input() method, in while loop within same method

Tags: c#, .net, loops, refactoring

```
namespace ClassesnObject
{
class Program
{

    public class myClass
    {
        string val;
        public static int val2 = 0;            

        public void bottle(string name)
        {
            val = name;
            val2++;
        }            

    }
    static ConsoleKeyInfo readkey = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
    static myClass myObj = new myClass();
    static void input()    //This is the problematic method
    {
        string name;
        bool con = true;   
        Console.WriteLine("Enter name: ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        myObj.bottle(name);
        while (con)
        {                
            Console.WriteLine("Want to enter more name(Y/N)? ");                
            readkey = Console.ReadKey();
            if (readkey.KeyChar == 'Y' || readkey.KeyChar == 'y') input();
            else if (readkey.KeyChar == 'N' || readkey.KeyChar == 'n') return;//Problem
            else continue;
        }
    } 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        input();
        Console.WriteLine("No. of entries are: " + myClass.val2);
        Console.ReadLine();                    
    }
}
```

When I'm in input() method, and in while loop pressing 'Y' or 'y' does the work, but 'N' or 'n' doesn't.
It seems like when pressing 'N' or 'n' it will not return until we have pressed 'N' or 'n' the times we have entered the names.

Comment: enter names in loop instead of recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are recursively calling `input()`. If you say `'y'` a few times then `'n'` it will have to walk back down the stack for each call to `input()`. You will have to press 'n' or 'N' for each time it has input was called.

Getting rid of some of the handy waving `ifs` might help...

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. But could you ellaborate?

Comment: Is there some way to directly exit from recursive called methods?

Comment: Not in C# - you need tail recursion.

Comment: Thanks, i will also try that.

Answer (score 1):

Enter names in loop instead of recursive call to `Input()` method, and use `ConsoleKey` to verify user input:

```
static void Input()
{
    ConsoleKey key;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter name: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        myObj.bottle(name);            

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Want to enter more name(Y/N)? ");
            key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
        } while (key != ConsoleKey.Y && key != ConsoleKey.N);

    } while (key == ConsoleKey.Y);
}
```

Going further I'd extracted inner loop and body of loop into own methods. This will show intent of your code to reader. Look - this code describes what exactly happening:

```
static void EnterNames()
{        
    do
    {
       EnterName();
    } 
    while (WantToEnterMoreNames());
}

static void EnterName()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter name: ");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    myObj.bottle(name);   
}

static bool WantToEnterMoreNames()
{        
    do
    {            
        Console.WriteLine("Want to enter more name(Y/N)? ");

        switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.Y: return true;
            case ConsoleKey.N: return false;
            default:
                continue;
        }
    } 
    while (true);
}
```

Comment: Good one. Not an if in sight :-)

Comment: Thanks, for such a great help.

Comment: Second way of coding is great, i will try to use this technique in future.